# How to do a convergence test on a complex series in Mathematica

Tags: series-expansion, convergence

I set the following to N=5, and want to do a convergence test on u:

```
    n = 5; u[r_, phi_, n_] := 
 Piecewise[{{BesselJ[1.5 r, n]*Exp[I n phi], 
    0 < r < 1/2}, {(BesselJ[3 r, n] + BesselY[3 r, n])*Exp[I n phi], 
    1/2 < r < 1}, {HankelH1[r, n]*Exp[I n phi], r > 1}}]
```

and the convergence test:

```
SumConvergence[u[r, phi, 5], n]
```

But the i get:

"SumConvergence::ivar: 5 is not a valid variable."

I try to set a number for it, but that is not accepted either.

How is this done correctly?

Comment: In an infinite series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$, there is an index $k$ that ranges over (say, positive) integers.  What is the index variable of your series? It's not `5` (therefore not `n`), since that is constant. The index should be the second argument of `SumConvergence[]`.

Comment: That is a 0. I show here a successful use of this command: u0[r_, phi_] := Sum[I^(-n) BesselJ[n, r] Exp[I n phi], {n, 0, 3}];
u[r_, phi_] := u0[r, phi] 
SumConvergence[u0[r, phi], n] . Which is different from the one above.

Comment: I get the `ivar` error with the code in your comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ccuO.png -- Is that a successful use? (You didn't give an answer to "what is the index variable?". The constant `0` cannot be an index variable, but I'm not sure whether "That is a 0" was meant to be an answer.)

Comment: This gives `True`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai4lk.png

Comment: So, if you mean the first level of N, then it is 0.

Comment: Try this: u0[r_, phi_] := Sum[I^(-n) BesselJ[n, r] Exp[I n phi], {n, 0, 3}];
u[r_, phi_] := u0[r, phi] 
SumConvergence[u0[r, phi], n]

Comment: I did try that. See the image.  Did you mean to clear `n` first? Your code does not do that so I left it equal to `5` as in the question.

Comment: I did the Clear[n], now I get different results :(. But this is with the function named here in the discussion, not the one in the topic description. That is still unresolved. Have you found a way to generate its partial sums?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case `SumConvergece` fails as

```
Clear[n]; 
u[r_, phi_, n_] := Piecewise[{{BesselJ[3/2 r, n]*Exp[I n phi], 
0 < r < 1/2}, {(BesselJ[3 r, n] + BesselY[3 r, n])*Exp[I n phi], 
1/2 < r < 1}, {HankelH1[r, n]*Exp[I n phi], r > 1}}]
SumConvergence[u[r, phi, n], n,Assumptions -> r > 1/2 && phi \[Element] Reals]
```

demonstrates. It works if the parameters are specified, e.g

```
SumConvergence[u[2, Pi/4, n], n]
```

> `True`